# Is there any way to parellelly grep through bz2 files

Tags: unix, grep, bz2

I recently found out this solution to less through compressed gz files parellelly based on the cores available.

```
find . -name "*.gz" | xargs -n 1 -P 3 zgrep -H '{pattern to search}'
```

P.S. 3 is the number of cores

I was wondering if there was a way to do it for bz2 files as well. 
Currently I am using this command:

```
find -type f -name '*.bz2' -execdir bzgrep "{text to find}" {} /dev/null \;
```

Comment: Just substitute `bzgrep` for `zgrep` in the `xargs`?

Comment: Eh? It's not the less that's parallelized, it's the grepping. Actually, you don't have `less` in your question anywhere at all... and you're parallelizing the easy way, multiple files at the same time but only one thread of execution per file, as opposed to the only-sometimes-possible way, decompressing the same file from multiple points in parallel (which requires the compressor to be configured to periodically reset itself and build a new table -- enabling parallel decoding at some cost to performance and output size).

Comment: Also, your current version of the gzip one won't work for all possible filenames, since it's taking the output from `find` in line-oriented form, but filenames are allowed to contain literal newlines. To be fully safe, you need to use NUL delimiters (which can't exist in filenames or other content represented by C strings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `*.gz` to `*.bz2`; change `zgrep` to `bzgrep`, and there you are.

For a bit of extra safety around unusual filenames, use `-print0` on the `find` end and `-0` on the `xargs`:

```
find . -name "*.bz2" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 3 bzgrep -H '{pattern to search}'
```